# Can't return the row number of first-filtered-row

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying many methods but still can't get the right row number.

I have this table, freezed at row 4 (Headers).

```
(Row)  Name   Car   Fee
5       A     333   1000
6       B     111   2000
7       C     222   3000
8       D     111   4000
9       E     222   5000
10      F     111   6000
```

I made a button to **Return the Row number** of **Selection** range. After I filter with criteria as "111", the table will show rows 6,8,10.

The code works fine when I select from row 6 to another row. But it turns error if I ONLY select row 6. Only returns row 1 infinitely.

Code works fine for this:

[image: IMG 1: code work fine.]

error - infinite row 1:

[image: IMG 2: error - infinite row 1]

The button VBA code:

```
Private Sub msg_Click()

Dim rng As Range, eaR As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each eaR In rng.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    MsgBox eaR.Row
Next eaR

End Sub
```

[Solved] And another problem is, the code returns duplicate row number if I select more than 2 cells in a row.

*Ex: If I select like IMG 1, it will return "6,6,8,8"*

**What can I do so it will only return "6,8"**

Please help me. Thank you very much!!!

**Note: I need to use Selection range because I will do things with just some rows in the Filtered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Private Sub msg_Click()

Dim rng As Range, eaR As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each eaR In rng
    If Not eaR.Rows.Hidden Then MsgBox eaR.Row
Next eaR

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well. Though the problem of Duplicate return of rows number still haven't solved yet.

Comment: `Set rng = Selection.Columns(1)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your help, but adding Columns didn't work for me. It returned only first row number, the next row didn't show. Anyway I do a workaround way by checking the number if it same as previous then skip.

Comment: Try it like this... For Each eaR In rng.Columns(1).Cells